# Zend Framework controller plugin performing HTTP Basic auth?

Tags: zend-framework, authentication, basic-authentication

How can I write a Zend Framework controller plugin that performs HTTP Basic auth (or digest) against all incoming requests?  If no authentication details (via the `Authorization` header) are provided, or authentication fails, I want to return the 401 status code (and not redirect to `/login` or similar).  (The application is a web service; it never returns `text/html`.)

(A possibly simpler re-stating of this problem is: how do you return user-defined status codes, and inhibit all further processing, from a controller plugin?)

Comment: Do you just want to display an error message and code to the user?

Answer (score 2):

I would start with the [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html) component and select either the [Http adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.adapter.http.html) or the [digest adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.adapter.digest.html) and I think you would probably want to build the plugin to evaluate the request at [routeStartup()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html).

You can then either put the error response in your default controller or you can build/alter the error controller to return the http response in what ever flavor you desire.

Good Luck